# Sql-How to retrieve data from the database having value present in json encode format by using php

Tags: mysql, sql

### Heading ##      [genre] => Array

```
    (
        [0] => History
        [1] => ACTION
        [2] => ROMANTIC
    )
```

[image]

In the genre object there are 3 array values present having name History, ACTION and ROMANTIC.

And in the genre column from the database you can see the data stored in json format. How I can retrieve the data in one sql query which having the matched array value(History, ACTION, ROMANTIC) present inside the genre object.

Comment: mysql version??

Answer (score 0):

I hope the `Genre` column is `JSON` data type and then use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `TABLE` 
WHERE 
    JSON_CONTAINS(genre, '["History", "ACTION", "ROMANTIC"]');
```

Check [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2NCobA9VdynEvTEiQhxwX/0)